# what's the client pc requirements for a VB.net using access database

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

does the client pc need to install anything for runing a VB.net application with access database ? (like microsoft office  or  something else ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they do. If they have MS Access, then no further tools are required. Otherwise they will need to install AccessDatabaseEngine.exe to handle the database operations. You can download that from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently making a VB.net application to run with Access and have had to install AccessDatabaseEngine.exe ect.

Helpful website that I've since saved which contains all the downloads you'll need:
[https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/...](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb)

Comment: Thanks nore,The best one in my case is SQLite then.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using ADO.NET and have selected the Assembly in the dependencies it will be part of the .NET Framework. Sometimes older Applications do need the Microsoft JET Driver copied into the windows directory. Do you have an error message?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Björn, No I use SQLite and I want to switch to Access database. I would like to know if the client Pc have to install any thing